# Using types from inside a .dll with C++

Tags: c++, dll

I am writing a C++ script that uses a 3rd party library stored in a `.dll` file.

I have been following [this example](https://youtu.be/JPQWQfDhICA?t=474) and have the following code:

```
if (HMODULE const hDLLLibrary = LoadLibraryA(MY_DLL_LIB)) {
    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.
    DLLType const aDLLFunction = GetProcAddress(hDLLLibrary, "aDLLFunction");
    DLLType result = aDLLFunction();
}
```

`aDLLFunction` returns an object of type `DLLType` .

The problem I have here is that the type `DLLType` is not recognised in my main script (`identifier is undefined` and so won't compile).

How can I get my main script to acknowledge and use types that are defined in the imported `.dll`?

Comment: You need some include file, distributed by the DLL author, that declares the types. For COM based DLLs also you may import a type library.

Comment: Those types should be exported by the DLL, and you should be able to import and use them. Something in the lines of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport?view=vs-2019

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis The linked article has an example of using it with classes.

Comment: You should use the `.h` file that comes with your DLL. It will contain the definitions of the functions available in the DLL.